# Sending a message using a channel ID saved with enmap

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to send an embed to a channel using the channels ID that's saved with enmap.
The channels were being saved as `<#123456789>`, which I solved using `replace()`. A console.log confirms that what's saved in that enmap entry is nothing but `123456789`.

However, when I try:
`client.channels.cache.get(chanID).send({ embed })` or:
`client.guild.channels.resolve(chanID).send({ embed })`
(`chanID` contains the channel ID retrieved from enmap.)

I get the error: `Cannot read property 'send' of null`.

The channels.resolve code works on another bot when the ID is entered directly.. so I don't see why this is throwing errors.. obviously being only a few days into JS isn't helping :)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

`

Comment: If you're using DiscordJS v12, you need to cache channels. You've got `client.guild.channels.resolve` when it should be `client.guild.channels.cache.resolve`.

Answer (score 0):

Enmap is not the error.
`client.guild.channels.resolve(chanID).send({ embed })` is not correct as `client.guild.channels` is not correctly formuled. Guild must be defined to do that. When you do `client.channels.cache.get(chanID).send({ embed })` it searches the channel in all the servers that the bot is joined.
Also, the Enmap value must be a string, not a number. Try it and tell me if your error has been resolved

EDIT: Cache almacenates when a channel is called with `client.on`. If you want to fetch it, use `client.channels.fetch(chanID)`. If you want to save it in the cache to evict waiting, use `client.channels.fetch(chanID, true)`.

Comment: Hi migue. Thanks for the response.. apologies for late repy.
`client.channels.cache.get(chanID).send({ embed })` does, of course, work if I use a channel ID. 
When I use a variable that contains a channel ID.. it stops working and gives the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` error.

Outputting the contents of the variable to console shows it contains nothing but a channel ID, no other characters or than the ID numbers.
I've tried everything I can think of, but keep getting the same error.
using toString() makes no difference either.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Hi @G.R, I found the error. In the cache, it almacenates all the things that the bot need to handle. What I mean is, you cannot fetch a channel from cache without interacting on it with `client.on`. If you have `client.on('message',...`, and you send a message in the desired channel, it will save that channel in cache and you can use it. **But**, I fond a solution to not cache! `client.channels.fetch(chanID)` should work. If you want to cache it, use `client.channels.fetch(chanID, true)` Hope it works!